# WordPress meta query wildcard

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a post from database with a `post_title` like `%Weapon%`.

I tried the code from bellow, but the `single.php` dies.

```
            $args = array(
                'numberposts'  => 20,
                'category'     => 4,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key' => 'title',
                    'value' => "Weapon",
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
            );
            // $posts = get_posts($args);

            query_posts( $args );
```

I want to get posts from the database where the `post_title` is like `%Weapon%`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress get\_posts by title like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103949/wordpress-get-posts-by-title-like)

Answer (score 0):

If to use "s"=>"Weapon" it will give you all posts that titles and contents contains "Weapon".

But if you want to get "title like" posts only, you need to add some SQL there.

```
$string="Weapon";
global $wpdb;
$theneededposts=$wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts 
  WHERE post_title
  LIKE '%".esc_sql($string)."%' "
);
if (empty($theneededposts)) $theneededposts=array();
$args = array(
           'numberposts'  => 20,
            'category'     => 4,
            'post__in'=>$theneededposts,
           );
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that code below helpful for you

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $title = 'Weapon';
    $myposts = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND  post_title LIKE '%s'", '%'. $wpdb->esc_like( $title ) .'%'  ) );

    foreach ( $myposts as $mypost ) 
    {
        $post = get_post( $mypost );
        //run your output code here
        echo $post->post_title;
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Hello, Every information store in  $post variable. Just <?php print_r( $post ); ?> to see all information about the post. You can display post content  <?php $post->post_content; ?> in this way.